# Is it possible to dedicate the physical screen of a vmware server machine to a guest vm graphically?

Tags: vmware-server, hardware

I have a vmware server 2.x running on ubuntu server (8.04). So the graphics card and the screen of the physical box are unused (I log in remotely and the host os has only the cli console installed).

I wonder if it is possible to assign this graphics card to a virtual machine directly and use it for the gui of this guest?

Or maybe if I add a second graphics card to the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible ;)

If you're not using the host OS for any other purpose, you may be better off loading the server with [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/). More efficient running just a hypervisor, rather than OS + Hypervisor.